# Attempting to run neo4j tutorial, get error: error: no suitable method found for run(String,Map<String,List>)

Tags: java, neo4j, javac

I am just learning how to use Neo4j. I went on their website and [saw one of their tutorials](https://neo4j.com/developer/). On that website, if you scroll down, you'll see their "Test-Drive Neo4j with Cypher" section, and the default one ("Social") has a "Friends of Friends" example. Furthermore, they have some code examples. I clicked on the "Java" one and saw an example of the `Social.java` program. Their instructions had four parts:

1. Download a Neo4j driver (they provide the link, and I downloaded that JAR)
2. Copy and paste code into `Social.java`
3. Compile with `javac -cp neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0.jar Social.java`
4. Run with `java -cp neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0.jar:. Social`

Unfortunately, step (3) fails. After trying to compile, I get the following error:

```
javac -cp neo4j-java-driver-1.0.0.jar Social.java  Social.java:25: error: no suitable method found for run(String,Map<String,List>)
        session.run(insertQuery,singletonMap("pairs",data)).consume();
               ^
method StatementRunner.run(Statement) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method StatementRunner.run(String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method StatementRunner.run(String,Record) is not applicable
  (actual argument Map<String,List> cannot be converted to Record by method invocation conversion)
method StatementRunner.run(String,Map<String,Object>) is not applicable
  (actual argument Map<String,List> cannot be converted to Map<String,Object> by method invocation conversion)
method StatementRunner.run(String,Value) is not applicable
  (actual argument Map<String,List> cannot be converted to Value by method invocation conversion) 1 error
```

I'm not sure how to fix it because I don't know the details of the `run`  method, and I assumed that since this was a tutorial with four simple steps, all stages should have worked correctly. My `javac` version is 1.7, if that matters.

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, it looks like an error in the examples. You can create a hashmap yourself instead of using the singletonMap causing the issue :

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("pairs", data);

session.run(insertQuery,parameters).consume();
```

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure it was something like that. Though with the changes above I seem to be getting an `Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.` error, but that's an issue for another day and there's probably better ways to learn neo4j.

Answer (score 3):

In the code they are using:

```
session.run(insertQuery,singletonMap("pairs",data)).consume();
```

replace this with the:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("pairs", data);

session.run(insertQuery,parameters).consume();
```